# How to get Unique Value from a table for different sessions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have procedure which creates `Unique Account ID` while creating `Accounts` in my application.

- `Max Account ID` is stored in another table(`Table ::MaxAccountID`).
- While creating user account,SP calls this table to get `Max Account ID`.

  Eg :Account ID :: MG110000021(110000021,we are getting from MaxAccountID Table)

We have used `TABLOCKX` to get `Unique Account ID`,as Same SP is being called in multiple sessions within fraction of seconds.

So each session will get unique `AccountID` with `TABLOCKX`.

This not solved my issue, still we are getting Same(duplicate) AccountID for different Sessions.

```
SELECT @OutPutID = AccountID 
FROM MaxAccountID WITH(TABLOCKX)  
UPDATE MaxAccountID SET AccountID =AccountID +1
```

There was transaction before calling Max AccountID value.

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC GetMax_AccountID @OutPutID OUTPUT
INSERT INTO AccountInfo(------------
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

`GetMax_AccountID` procedure contains below,@OutPutID as output para

```
SELECT @OutPutID = AccountID 
FROM MaxAccountID WITH(TABLOCKX)  
UPDATE MaxAccountID SET AccountID =AccountID +1
```

Comment: Nothing is stopping another select before the update.  You need to wrap that in a transaction.

Comment: Besides @Blam's point, in SQL Server the best way to do this is to use an IDENTITY column for AccountID

Comment: You must be calling this SP from a client, right? If exclusive lock is not working for you on the sql server side then how about giving an explicit lock construct on the client before calling this SP?

Comment: who is making inserts to MaxAccountID table, your SP or some trigger on Account table?

Comment: I seriously doubt that transaction you posted is enforced in the call to GetMax_AccountID.  Wrap GetMax_AccountID in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help. It will return the value directly.

```
UPDATE MAXID_Task 
SET ID=ID+1
OUTPUT deleted.ID
```

If you need it in the variable:

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE (ID int)

UPDATE MAXID_Task 
SET ID=ID+1
OUTPUT deleted.ID
INTO @Result

SELECT @OutPutID = ID FROM @Result
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am concerned exclusive and shared locks work only if you select in transaction. if you don't, your with(tablockx) won't block the table. try to wrap your update in transaction. then you can be sure a table is locked  (unless some other is query is selecting with(nolock)).